# 2002 Toyota Sequoia not starting

Tags: battery, toyota, starting, sequoia

I recently bought a 2002 Toyota Sequoia with 130,000 miles, it ran perfectly for about a week, but one of the handles had broken off inside the cabin. I searched up videos on how to replace the handle, and followed it step by step. One of the steps was to disconnect the battery, so I did. When I finished up and reattached the battery terminal I noticed that is was still loose, so I tightened up a bit more and accidentally broke it. I then replaced the terminal, made sure to clean the posts and terminals themselves, I made sure that there was a good connection between the wires and terminals, I had to cut off a bit of the wire that was connected to the old terminal, but still had more than enough to strip the casing and connect it to another terminal. When I reconnected them and when to turn the car on, it started normally. I then turned it off and tried to turn it back on, the car cranked, sounded like it was about to fully start and suddenly turned off. I tried to start it again, but same thing happened, cranked, started for half a second and suddenly died. I tried it for a third time and gave it some gas this time, the car started revved up and died as soon as I let off the gas. Keep in mind that this was all after it had started normally. I tried to diagnose the problem, along with some of my more mechanically inclined friends. We tried jumpstarting, at first it would crank, make a loud screeching noise and turn off instantly, we tried using a battery off a different car that we knew was good, checking and redoing terminals, banging on starter while trying to start it, checking all the fuses, nothing. The head lights and high beams still come on, and dim down when trying to start the car, but nothing happens. Now all we get is a click when trying to start the car. We have no idea what it could be seeing as how it had literally started normally moments before it wouldn’t start anymore. Any ideas on what could have happened?

Comment: Can you add a photo of the repair to the battery terminal connector?

Comment: It sounds to me like it could be a security related issue. Is there a blinking green light on the dash at anytime after you key on? Not sure how Toyota's security indicator looks ... it might be a lock or key symbol, but it is most commonly green.